# vpn with dynamic ddns update ip

Tags: networking, openvpn, openwrt

I am using openvpn in linux in a router which has openwrt.

My problem is that every day ,in order for the vpn to work,I have to change manually my IP from the noip account.

I am using an account,hostname at noip,so as gateway for my vpn connection I use that.

Can I do sth for that?

I am not sure if the 2nd line below is needed,though.I also removed it but still the same.

openvpn:

```
list 'push' 'redirect-gateway def1' 
list 'push' 'dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1'
```

I am using this:
[image]

where I enter my hostname and username

Answer (score 0):

It is possible not completely obvious the two questions are connected. At any rate:

1.Remove the *push DHCP option DNS..* statement, that's not strictly necessary;
 2.make sure your no-ip configuration is correctly set up; if it is, you should see the IP address of your name, your-name.no-ip.biz for instance, updated to your new IP address within seconds of its change.

This way, in your client side configuration file, you may refer to your home server as *your-name.no-ip.biz*, no need to provide an IP address.

To check your IP from the CLI (faster than going with you browser to www.whatismyipaddress.com or the like), use:

```
  wget checkip.dyndns.org:80 -O - -o /dev/null | cut -d" " -f6 | sed 's/<\/body><\/html>//
```

Comment: :First of all ,I could see my IP of my name,this wasn't a problem.I was refering using my hostname and not my IP.So,until now all was ok.Now, I removed the push DNS statement,I did openvpn restart but still I can't connect to vpn..

Comment: :Any ideas what causes this?Thank you.

Comment: :Hello,I updated my post maybe you see something wrong?